# Me da un error a la hora de acumular la suma , me aparece " Variable local no asignada"

Tags: c#

```
public static void BucleFor() {
    int i,numero, dato, repuesta;

    Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de numeros a sumar");
    dato = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    for (i=1; i<=dato; i++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("introdusca el dato " + i +"a Sumar");
         numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
         repuesta = repuesta + numero;
         Console.WriteLine("la suma es :" +repuesta);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aunque la respuesta de @DMG soluciona el problema y es totalmente correcta, no lo explica, por eso mi respuesta trata de ampliar un poco la información sobre el tema.

Hay que diferenciar entre variable local y de instancia. Una variable de instancia es la que está definida a nivel de clase. La variable local se define a nivel de método.

En la cuestión que nos ocupa, esta diferencia es importante, ya que en el caso de `int` por ejemplo, si se trata de una variable de instancia, esta se inicializa a su valor por defecto, que en el caso de `int` es 0, sin embargo si se trata de una variable local, su valor es indefinido. Por ejemplo, veamos este código:

```
class prueba
{
     int i;
     public void metodo()
     {
          int j;
          Console.WriteLine(i);
          Console.WriteLine(j);
     }
 }
```

Esto no compilará, ya que se quejará de que la variable local `j` no está asignada. Sin embargo, si ponemos `int j = 0;`, compilará correctamente y `Console.WriteLine(i);` escribirá un `0`, demostrando que la variable de instancia ha sido inicializada automáticamente.

Answer (score 5):

solo inicializa la variable respuesta

```
int i,numero, dato, repuesta=0;
```

saludos.

Comment: Gracias :Dsssss